# SQL Alter Column in table From Bit to Int

Tags: sql-server, bit, alter-table

So What I am looking to do is alter a table and change a column from an BIT to INT. Although currently in the column there are null values I would like to change to -1 and not allow null. Since BIT only holds 0 and 1, how would I Alter the Column to an INT and Set the Null values to -1

I was thinking something along the lines of

```
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME
ALTER COLUMN COLUMNAME INT SET DEFAULT -1
WHEN NULL THEN CAST(-1 AS INT)
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: sql management studio, I'm going to be writing this as a script instead of using the generator, because I'll need to keep the values of the current column without loosing them

Comment: Is there a special reason why you don't do it step by step - changing type, updating data, adding not null constraint?

Comment: So change the type, then change values that are null to -1, then add not null constraint, and finally I would need to set the default value to -1? @MartinK.

Comment: sure, i guess you will do this only once

Comment: sql management studio is not a DBMS it's a client tool. But since it only supports SQL Server, I added the corresponding tag

Comment: Ok thanks guys, and @MartinK, yeah I'll only need to do this once.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hope the following code snippet will help you out.

```
--Created table for testing
CREATE TABLE Test(COl Bit)

--Insertint values
INSERT INTO Test VALUES(0)
INSERT INTO Test VALUES(NULL)
INSERT INTO Test VALUES(1)

--Change the column type
ALTER TABLE Test ALTER COLUMN COL INT

-- Update null values to -1
UPDATE Test SET COL = ISNULL(COL,-1) WHERE COL is NULL

-- Changing the column to not null
ALTER TABLE Test ALTER COLUMN COL int NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, this sample worked fine for me. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 2):

proper Syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE {TABLENAME} 
ALTER {COLUMNNAME} {TYPE} {NULL|NOT NULL} 
CONSTRAINT {CONSTRAINT_NAME} DEFAULT {DEFAULT_VALUE}
```

Do it step by step as shown below

```
create table test2(id int not null identity primary key ,
 col bit);


ALTER TABLE test2
ALTER COLUMN col INT NULL --Alter to change the type to INT

alter table test2
add constraint dflt default -1 for col  --Alter to create a default value
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahul too for the help !

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to create a new column and update it's values in three separate update statements, then delete the old column and rename the new one